# Python unittest: Can we repeat Unit test case execution for a configurable number of times?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Can we repeat Unit test case execution for a configurable number of times?

For example, I have a Unit test script named `Test_MyHardware` that contains couple of test cases `test_customHardware1` and `test_customHardware2`.

Is there a way to repeat the execution of `test_customHardware1` 200 times and `test_customHardware2` 500 times with Python's unittest module?

**Note**: The above case presented is simplified. In practise, we would have 1000s of test cases.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63712502/9201239

Answer (score 2):

While the [unittest module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) has no options for that, there are several ways to achieve this:

- You can (ab)use the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to repeatedly calling a test method. Remember: Test methods are just like normal methods and you can call them yourself. There is no special magic required.
- You can use [decorators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) to achieve this:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import unittest

  def repeat(times):
      def repeatHelper(f):
          def callHelper(*args):
              for i in range(0, times):
                  f(*args)

          return callHelper

      return repeatHelper


  class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):
      @repeat(10)
      def test_me(self):
          print "You will see me 10 times"

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      unittest.main()
  ```

Comment: Note that this approach won't work if you have something going on in `setUp`

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to call `unittest.main()` multiple times with `exit=False`. This example takes the number of times to repeat as an argument and calls `unittest.main` that number of times:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--repeat", dest="repeat", help="repeat tests")
(args, unitargs) = parser.parse_known_args()
unitargs.insert(0, "placeholder") # unittest ignores first arg
# add more arguments to unitargs here
repeat = vars(args)["repeat"]
if repeat == None:
    repeat = 1
else:
    repeat = int(repeat)
for iteration in range(repeat):
    wasSuccessful = unittest.main(exit=False, argv=unitargs).result.wasSuccessful()
    if not wasSuccessful:
        sys.exit(1)
```

This allows much greater flexibility since it will run all tests the user requested the number of times specified.

You'll need to import:

```
import unittest
import argparse
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these 2 lines of code helped me. Multiple tests can be added in addition to 'test_customHardware1' in below array.

```
repeat_nos = 10
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(unittest.TestSuite (map (Test_MyHardware, ['test_customHardware1' ]*repeat_nos)))]
```