# How can I repeat each test multiple times in a py.test run?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to run each selected py.test item an arbitrary number of times, sequentially.
I don't see any standard py.test mechanism for doing this.

I attempted to do this in the `pytest_collection_modifyitems()` hook.  I modified the list of items passed in, to specify each item more than once.  The first execution of a test item works as expected, but that seems to cause some problems for my code.

Further, I would prefer to have a unique test item object for each run, as I use id (item) as a key in various reporting code.  Unfortunately, I can't find any py.test code to duplicate a test item, `copy.copy()` doesn't work, and `copy.deepcopy()` gets an exception.

Can anybody suggest a strategy for executing a test multiple times?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In order to run each test a number of times, we will programmatically parameterize each test as the tests are being generated.

First, let's add the parser option (include the following in one of your conftest.py's):

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--repeat', action='store',
        help='Number of times to repeat each test')
```

Now we add a "pytest_generate_tests" hook. Here is where the magic happens.

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if metafunc.config.option.repeat is not None:
        count = int(metafunc.config.option.repeat)

        # We're going to duplicate these tests by parametrizing them,
        # which requires that each test has a fixture to accept the parameter.
        # We can add a new fixture like so:
        metafunc.fixturenames.append('tmp_ct')

        # Now we parametrize. This is what happens when we do e.g.,
        # @pytest.mark.parametrize('tmp_ct', range(count))
        # def test_foo(): pass
        metafunc.parametrize('tmp_ct', range(count))
```

Running without the repeat flag:

```
(env) $ py.test test.py -vv
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2 -- env/bin/python
collected 2 items 

test.py:4: test_1 PASSED
test.py:8: test_2 PASSED

=========================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

Running with the repeat flag:

```
(env) $ py.test test.py -vv --repeat 3
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2 -- env/bin/python
collected 6 items 

test.py:4: test_1[0] PASSED
test.py:4: test_1[1] PASSED
test.py:4: test_1[2] PASSED
test.py:8: test_2[0] PASSED
test.py:8: test_2[1] PASSED
test.py:8: test_2[2] PASSED

=========================== 6 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

Further reading:

- https://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#well-specified-hooks
- https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html

Comment: While this method may work, I used your suggestion to find a simpler way, which doesn't require any parametrized arguments, etc.  I will post it and accept it as the answer.  Thanks for your suggestion; it led me directly to my solution.

Comment: Working on a new project, so I came here to figure out how I had done this previously. I now understand that this solution does not require me to declare a fixture parameter to each test. So I am selecting this answer as correct, and I am using your strategy on my new project. Thanks!

Comment: How does one repeat the entire test file in order? Here test 1 is run 3 times, what about running 1,2,3 (in order) 3 times?

Comment: Can it be made to repeat tests in the order though? I mean, if you want to call two tests, you usually do `pytest -k "test_foo or test_bar"` and it results in `foo` and `bar` being in order. However, when I use your code and do a `pytest --repeat=99 -k "test_foo or test_bar"`, instead of calling `foo` and `bar` repeatedly it calls 99 times `foo` and then goes on to call `bar`.

Comment: how about running at once,, I am actually trying to test how our server can hold with 1000 request in one go,,?

Answer (score 137):

One possible strategy is parameterizing the test in question, but not explicitly using the parameter.

For example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('execution_number', range(5))
def run_multiple_times(execution_number):
    assert True
```

The above test should run five times.

Check out the parametrization documentation: https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: This will execute the test the number of times specified in the test file.  It doesn't achieve my goal of executing a test an arbitrary number of times, as specified by a command-line option.

Comment: My apologies, I completely misunderstood your question. I think I've figured out how to do what you want, which I'll add as another answer (since this one is completely wrong :).

Comment: I'm glad this answer is here.  I think it adds to the context for future users looking for possible solutions.

Comment: Nice solution if you want to "hardcode" number of times test should be executed

Comment: what is particularly cool about this is the ability to use n to say nth-time {X} happens.

This is just creating a single parameter test though, so you can use any single-dimensional data-source such as an array to make the tests more readable. I just took a series of canned names and this automatically interpolates them so that you know which precise one is failing.Very nice feature for test readability

Comment: This is particularly useful for debugging the occasional "flakey" test that fails 1 out 25 times due to side effects of fixture data etc.

Comment: When you're ALREADY using parametrize, just multiply: @pytest.mark.parametrize("names", [params]*20)

Answer (score 80):

The pytest module [pytest-repeat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-repeat/) exists for this purpose, and I recommend using modules where possible, rather than re-implementing their functionality yourself.

To use it simply add `pytest-repeat` to your `requirements.txt` or `pip install pytest-repeat`, then execute your tests with `--count n`.

Comment: `warnings.warn("Repeating unittest class tests not supported")` https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-repeat/blob/9587709fdcc0b4af1b82dd82ac4374f93fac2810/pytest_repeat.py#L44-L45

Answer (score 8):

Based on Frank T's suggestion, I found a very simple solution in the `pytest_generate_tests()` callout:

```
parser.addoption ('--count', default=1, type='int', metavar='count', help='Run each test the specified number of times')

def pytest_generate_tests (metafunc):
    for i in range (metafunc.config.option.count):
        metafunc.addcall()
```

Now executing `py.test --count 5` causes each test to be executed five times in the test session.

And it requires no changes to any of our existing tests.

Comment: metafunc.addcall() is deprecated, which is why I preferred .parametrize() in my implementation. See also: https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#_pytest.python.Metafunc.addcall

Comment: Your solution required me to add a parameter/funcarg to each of my 1,000 existing tests, which I didn't want to do. 

There is likely a .parametrize() equivalent to my simple solution, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Working on a new project, so I came here to figure out how I had done this previously.  I now understand that your solution does not require me to declare a fixture parameter to each test.  So I am selecting your original answer as correct, and I am using your strategy on my new project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

While `pytest-repeat` (the most popular answer) doesn't work for `unittest` class tests, [`pytest-flakefinder`](https://github.com/dropbox/pytest-flakefinder) does:

```
pip install pytest-flakefinder
pytest --flake-finder --flake-runs=5 tests...
```

Before finding `test-flakefinder`, I wrote a little hack of a script that does a similar thing. You can find it [here](https://github.com/stas00/toolbox/blob/master/python/unittest/unittest-run-repeat). The top of the script includes instructions to how it can be run.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `pytest-repeat`

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I've seen here, and given that I already do some filtering of tests in [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems), my method of choice is the following. In `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--count', default=1, type=int, metavar='count', help='Run each test the specified number of times')


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    count = config.option.count
    items[:] = items * count  # add each test multiple times
```

Comment: To avoid a warning, `type='int'` should be `type=int`

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a simple solution for a long time. I just had to run one test n-number of times. He shouldn't have fallen once. I solved this problem as simply and stupidly as possible, but it worked for me.

```
def run_multiple_times(number):
    i = 0
    while i < number:
        #test
        i += 1
run_multiple_times(5)
```