# How can I repeat a test module in py.test?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I would like to repeat a test module N times.
The order is very important.

*content of test_stress.py*

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("class_setup_teardown")
class TestStressRobot:
    def test_1(self):
        print "\nstressing part 1..."
        assert True

    def test_2(self):
        print "\nstressing part 2..."
        assert True

    def test_3(self):
        print "\nstressing part 3..."
        assert True
```

When I run ***py.test --repeat=2***, the output is:

> test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_1[0] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_1[1] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_2[0] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_2[1] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_3[0] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_3[1] ✓

I don't want it to be repeated per test, but per test module.

Is it possible to have something like that?

> test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_1[0] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_2[0] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_3[0] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_1[1] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_2[1] ✓
>   test_stress.pyTestStressRobot.test_3[1] ✓

Comment: If the order matters, you might be organising your tests incorrectly. Have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21764473/3001761

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pytestmark = [pytest.mark.usefixtures('module_scoped_fun')]
```

at module level with a module scoped parametrized fixture?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

pytest --flake-finder --flake-runs=runs

https://github.com/dropbox/pytest-flakefinder

Comment: I tried flakefinder, it doesn't execute the tests in the order the tests are written.