# How to run a pytest method multiple times?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I am trying to run a pytest method multiple times using pytest-repeat but i am getting a warning and its running only once

```
from page.to_run_login import RegisterLogin
from utilites.testStatus import TestStatus
import unittest
import pytest



@pytest.mark.usefixture("oneTimeSetUp","setUp")
class RegisterTest(unittest.TestCase):

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
    self.rg = RegisterLogin(self.driver)
    self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_registerLink(self):
    self.rg.register()
    self.rg.select_state_name()
    self.rg.select_city_name()
    self.rg.select_ready_wait()
    self.rg.select_ready_pay()
    self.rg.select_submit()
```

In terminal i am executing using this command py.test -s -v  test/to_test_login.py --count 2

Comment: From the readme: _Unfortunately pytest-repeat is not able to work with unittest.TestCase test classes. These tests will simply always run once, regardless of --count, and show a warning._

Comment: is there any other way where i can run it multiple times??

Comment: For unittest see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63712502/9201239

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
 def test_registerLink(self):
    for i in range(100):
        self.rg.register()
        self.rg.select_state_name()
        self.rg.select_city_name()
        self.rg.select_ready_wait()
        self.rg.select_ready_pay()
        self.rg.select_submit()
        self.rg.driver.back()
        self.rg.driver.refresh()
```

I was able to solve it by doing this

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 31, 2020 there is a better way to do this. See https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/

---

Simply `pip install pytest-repeat` and use `--count`. Example: `pytest --count=10 test_file.py`

Comment: That won't work for tests that inherit ``unittest.TestCase``.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `pytest` with a test that inherits `unittest.TestCase`, there's a simple way of repeating it by using the [parameterized](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/) Python library:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from parameterized import parameterized

class RepeatTests(TestCase):
    @parameterized.expand([[]] * 5)
    def test_repeat_this_test_with_parameterized(self):
        print("Hello!")
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Output:

```sh
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
```

Comment: (Install with ``pip install parameterized`` before running that example.)