# Run a directory of pytests multiple times

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

I want to run a directory of tests multiple times.

In [How can I repeat each test multiple times in a py.test run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764473/how-can-i-repeat-each-test-multiple-times-in-a-py-test-run), an answer was given to use module `pytest-repeat`. This module allows you to use a `--count=n` argument.

That argument makes pytest run each testcase inside of each test module *n* times in a row, before moving on to the next testcase, and then to the next test module.

This is a problem when tests are non re-entrant - the teardown code needs to be executed in order for repeated runs to succeed, or subsequent tests to succeed.

I want a way to run the entire directory, top-to-bottom, and then run it again top-to-bottom, etc., *n* times.

Barring that, I want a way to run each individual test module from beginning to end *n* times, rather than running each testcase inside the module *n* times.

In fewer words: The `--count=n` argument provided by the `pytest-repeat` module incurs repetition at the testcase level. I want repetition at the test module level, or, better yet, at the directory level.

Comment: The next question is: why do you need to run the whole test suite multiple times?

Comment: To check for intermittent failures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repeat each test multiple times in a py.test run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764473/how-can-i-repeat-each-test-multiple-times-in-a-py-test-run)

Comment: @gold_cy I referenced that question in the OP and explained why it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

> I want a way to run the entire directory, top-to-bottom, and then run it again top-to-bottom, etc., n times.

You can do this with [a bit of shell](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times-in-terminal-and-powershell-5af76df8d123).

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo "Run ${i}"; pytest; done;
```